# use android recognizer intent to do continuous speech recognition with little user interaction

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to use android recognizer intent to do continuous speech recognition with little user interaction.
However, when the google dialog box get the following error and stop, I cannot detect it and do anything:

Didn't catch that. Try speaking again.
Try again

Any way to improve that?

```
    intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
 
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
     

     intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
     RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);

    String mylanguage;

    mylanguage = "en-US";

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, mylanguage);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE,
            mylanguage);

    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
```

Comment: The Google speech recognizer isn't made for continuous recognition.  You'll need to use another library and handle the recording yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others, I found the followings:-

1. 9781118183489.zip
   ISBN: 9781118183489
   Title: Professional Android Sensor Programming

## File                                 Description

README.txt                           Read Me
AndroidSensorProgrammingSource.zip   Source code for the companion app that was used in the book examples.
GastAppActivity_play.apk             Android package from built from the contents of AndroidSensorProgrammingSource.zip that can be installed on a device. The companion app is also available from Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=root.gast.playground.

2. gast-lib-master.zip
   https://github.com/gast-lib